# perl check if filename that matches certain pattern exists in directory

Tags: perl

I'm using in my perl script the following code to check if a file exists

```
unless (-e "$inputdir/filetocheck.txt") {}
```

I now want to use a wildcard character in this command

```
unless (-e "$inputdir/*check.txt") {}
```

to check if there is any file that end with "check".

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You need to replace `-e` with [the `glob()` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html)